# Form Validation is still submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that validates and is working as expected but the form still submits even though it is prompting a validation error. Tried various different things but can't seem to make it stop submitting the form with incorrect validation.

```js
function Validate() {
  const name = document.forms.ValidateForm.name.value;
  console.log(name);

  if (name === "" ||
    name.includes('0') || name.includes('1') ||
    name.includes('2') || name.includes('3') ||
    name.includes('4') || name.includes('5') ||
    name.includes('6') || name.includes('7') ||
    name.includes('8') || name.includes('9')) {
    window.alert("Office Name cannot be Empty");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (name.length < 3) {
    alert("Office Name must be more than 3 characters");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ValidateForm" onsubmit="return Validate();" id="ValidateForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add Office">
</form>
```

Comment: I would skip the in-line `onsubmit` and use js `addEventListener()` with `event.preventDefault()` and `form.submit()`

Answer (score 4):

The issue in your code is because you're calling the `focus()` method on the *string* returned from the `input` element, not the `input` itself. This is causing an error to be thrown which means that `return false` is never hit.

```js
function Validate() {
  const nameField = document.forms.ValidateForm.name;
  const name = nameField.value;
  console.log(name);

  if (name === "" ||
    name.includes('0') || name.includes('1') ||
    name.includes('2') || name.includes('3') ||
    name.includes('4') || name.includes('5') ||
    name.includes('6') || name.includes('7') ||
    name.includes('8') || name.includes('9')) {
    window.alert("Office Name cannot be Empty");
    nameField.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (name.length < 3) {
    alert("Office Name must be more than 3 characters");
    nameField.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ValidateForm" onsubmit="return Validate();" id="ValidateForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add Office">
</form>
```

That being said, and as [@mykaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599011/mykaf) mentioned in the comments, this issue, along with the quality of your code, can be improved by removing the inline `onclick` attribute and binding your event handler in JS.

Also note the use of a regular expression to check for an integer in the entered 'name' string.

```js
const nameField = document.querySelector('#name');

document.querySelector('#ValidateForm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  const name = nameField.value;
  if (name === "" || /[0-9]/.test(name)) {
    alert("Office Name cannot be Empty");
    e.preventDefault();
    nameField.focus();
  }
  else if (name.length < 3) {
    alert("Office Name must be more than 3 characters");
    e.preventDefault();
    nameField.focus();
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ValidateForm" id="ValidateForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add Office">
</form>
```

Comment: Good catch! And an error like this can be hard to find when the form auto-submits anyway. A try/catch block with a `return false` in the catch can help determine the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use preventDefault().

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ValidateForm" onsubmit="Validate(e);" id="ValidateForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add Office">
</form>

function Validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const name = document.forms.ValidateForm.name.value;
  console.log(name);

  if (name === "" ||
    name.includes('0') || name.includes('1') ||
    name.includes('2') || name.includes('3') ||
    name.includes('4') || name.includes('5') ||
    name.includes('6') || name.includes('7') ||
    name.includes('8') || name.includes('9')) {
    window.alert("Office Name cannot be Empty");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (name.length < 3) {
    alert("Office Name must be more than 3 characters");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Event::preventDefault()` to halt the form's submission. Also call `focus()` on the input, not its value.

You can use `try/catch` to avoid code duplication.

Also your error messages could be more descriptive:

```js
const nameField = document.querySelector('#name');

document.querySelector('#ValidateForm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  const {value} = nameField;
  try {
    if (/[0-9]+/.test(value)) throw 'Office name cannnot contain digits';
    if (value.length < 3) throw 'Office Name must be more than 3 characters';
  } catch (m) {
    alert(m);
    e.preventDefault();
    nameField.focus();
  }
})
```

```css
sdf
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="ValidateForm" id="ValidateForm">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Add Office">
</form>
```